# Add refiners 'RefinableStringXX' to the SharePoint refinement panel using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have created a custom managed metadata field which is managed to one of my terms in the terms store. I have set up the 'RefinableString05' to my custom managed metadata crawl property as shown below.

[image]

I want to add this 'RefinableString05' in the Refinement webpart not from UI but using PowerShell script as I am scripting all my configurations.

[image]

Any help!!

Comment: Were you able to solve this using PowerShell? I'm also looking for the same thing.